# How does EL search for an attribute?

Tags: jsp, el, taglib

How does EL search for an attribute in JSP?
and how to disable it?

does any one know the performance of EL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In EL, if an object is not an implicit object it searches through the various scopes for an object of the given name. The order in which the search takes place is below:

1. Page scope
2. Request scope
3. Session scope
4. Application scope

To disable EL: `<%@ page isELIgnored ="true" %>`

Answer (score 0):

An EL is resolved using an ELResolver chain. The order of the EL resolvers is as following:

- `ImplicitObjectELResolver`
- `ELResolver`s registered via this method, in the order in which they are registered.
- `MapELResolver`
- `ListELResolver`
- `ArrayELResolver`
- `BeanELResolver`
- `ScopedAttributeELResolver`

Each token of EL is given this resolver chain to resolve.